# Import module from other directory in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I know this question has been asked thousands of times, but I still don't get the correct answer and stumble upon the same problem always.

I have the following file:

```
application/app/__init__.py
```

Here, I have some variable, let it be `x`.

Then, I have another file here:

```
application/tests/test_1.py
```

In `test_1.py` I do this:

```
from app import x
```

And, being in the `application` folder, I run:

```
python3 tests/test_1.py
```

But the following error happens:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

One solution that works is, inside `test_1.py`, add:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from app import db
```

Then if I do:

```
cd tests
python3 test_1.py
```

It works perfectly, but I don't want that `sys.path.append` and also I would like to do

```
python3 tests/test_1.py
```

Another solution is to explicitly modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but again, I wouldn't like to do this. Isn't there a clean solution to this problem?

Comment: If you run a file as a script you need to use absolute imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not manually "hack" the sys.path. This is a bad practice "quick fix" that you've probably learned from stackoverflow answers.

Python looks for imports in either the site-packages folder or in the PYTHONPATH. The easiest way to get your local folder into the site-packages is using

```
pip install --editable path/to/myfolder
```

You only need a setup.py in your program "myfolder" with the following contents

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='myfolder")
```

The name "myfolder" is only important in case you want to uninstall it. But eventually this will create a symlink of your myfolder in the environments site-packages, and you can continue editing as before. But your program works "as if installed".

This is way more flexible than changing the PYTHONPATH.

As for the other comment:
When `application' is linked to site-packages and thereby recognized via sys.path,

```
from app import x
```

is an absolute import, since 'app' is a folder inside the top level folder 'application'.